# issue about willAnimateRotate and didRotateFrom when doing an rotation

Tags: iphone

What I am having so far is

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSLog(@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation");
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"PortraitUpsideDown");
        // Do method A
    } else {
        [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        // Do method B
    } 
}
```

and

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation");
    if( fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        NSLog(@"OrientationPortrait or PortraitUpsideDown");
        [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        // Do method B
    } else {
        NSLog(@"From else");
        [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        // Do method A
    }
}
```

My logic is after hitting the RUN from xcode, `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` is going to be called because I set **Supported Device Orientation** to be **UpsideDown** from **Summary** of **MyApp.xcodeproj**. Moreover, I also think that `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` should not be called because we have just started the app yet. It means there are no previous states at all.

Unfortunately, this is what I got after doing the debugger

> 2012-02-11 12:04:08.776 MyApp[7505:10703] willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation :
>
> 2012-02-11 12:04:08.776 MyApp[7505:10703] PortraitUpsideDown
>
> 2012-02-11 12:04:08.778 MyApp[7505:10703] didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation :
>
> 2012-02-11 12:04:08.779 MyApp[7505:10703] OrientationPortrait or
>   PortraitUpsideDown

I am getting lost now. Does anyone have any ideas about the issue, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues with rotation, similar to yours. The short version is that the will and did methods are not 100% reliable. You should try rapidly rotating back and forth and see what happens. It could be because I am pretty new, or it could be an actual bug. What I did was, in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:, check the current orientation and act accordingly:

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) {
// do your portrait stuff
} else {
// do your landscape stuff
}
```

Before I found the UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortait test I was actually checking the frame to see if self.view.frame.size.width > self.view.frame.size.height, and that is also reliable but kind of ugly.

Either way is reliable. I have a couple apps in the store, QPalettes and QColor, that do rotation on a bunch of user-created onscreen elements. What I had to do is store the dimensions, and after didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation I check the new dimensions and if they are different, re-draw everything onscreen. Contact me if you'd like a promo code to check out the rotation in either app (they rotate the same - QColor is more complex since it also draws intersections).

Enjoy,

Damien

Comment: I just figured it out... In my opinion, the default orientation is Poitrait. Therefore, if we set orientation to be UpSideDown, so **willAnimateRotate** should be UpSideDown and **didRotateFrom** should be Poitrait.